# Brew install node error?

Tags: node.js, terminal, installation, homebrew, symlink

```
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.
```

I get this error trying to install node using brew, how do I fix it? I've heard about using sudo and other methods, but I know some of these methods can lead to future problems, so I want to make sure I'm doing the right fix.

Do note, I literally just uninstalled node manually by deleting the  necessary files in each folder that was listed on a website describing how to manually uninstall. Then I tried to install again using brew giving me this error. The reason I wanted to install it again was because I had an issue with permissions installing global packages and a solution to reinstall using brew was recommended.

Comment: `brew doctor` - output?

Comment: `You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar` 
`Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run 'brew link' on these:
  node`

Comment: I run "brew link node" and the same error comes up

Comment: Looks like you have some options under `brew link --help`. Try some of those maybe. I'm not too sure.

Comment: I am reinstalling it, because of permission issues installing global packages. probably something to with it I should of mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!!

Because I had used sudo in the past with other commands not realising the potential issues it causes down the road, several files and directories in /usr/local were now owned by root.

To get rid of these, I took back ownership of all of the files and directories under /usr/local using the command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```